# Appropriate statistical test for comparing two different intersections of three sets?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am trying to determine the best way to measure differences in the size of two different intersections of four sets. In other words, if I have the following four sets of genes:

```
 Set A: under positive selection only in species with trait X
________
gene 1
gene 2
gene 3
gene 6
gene 7
gene 8
```

```
 Set B: under intensified selection only in species WITHOUT trait X
________
gene 4
gene 5
gene 3
gene 6
```

```
 Set C: under intensified selection only in species with trait X
________
gene 2
gene 8
gene 9
gene 10
gene 11
gene 12
```

```
Set D: under positive selection only in species WITHOUT trait X
________
gene 4
gene 11
gene 12
gene 13
```

I'd like to know if there is a statistically significant difference in the number of genes in A ∩ C (gene 2, gene 8) versus B ∩ D (gene 4).

Also, note that by definition, A ∩ D and B ∩ C are empty sets (genes cannot be under positive selection in BOTH species with and without trait X, nor can they be under purifying selection in BOTH species with and without trait X).

Ideally, if you can point me towards a way to test this in R, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do the genes in Set A have some distinct characteristic versus the definition of Set B and of Set C? Also are these really different genes, or classifications of the *same* gene measured of different randomly sampled units, like a set of 12 cancer biopsies and the KRAS mutations (like WT/mutant A/mutant B)?

Comment: @AdamO, Set A is a list of genes under positive selection in a group of organisms with a trait of interest; Set B is a list of genes under intensified selection in the group of organisms with the trait of interest; and Set C is a list of genes under intensified selection in the group of organisms WITHOUT the trait of interest. They truly are different genes. Perhaps importantly- and I'll edit my question to reflect this- by definition, sets B and C have a null overlap (a gene cannot be under intensified selection in BOTH species with and without the trait of interest).

Comment: I also slightly misspecified the sets of interest; there are actually four such sets total, and I want to compare two of the unions thereof. I have updated the original question.